# perl regex is inconsistent when searching through global variable

Tags: regex, perl

I have a simple perl script which queries the dml (ignore the db->query bit if it looks strange - I am not using the DBI library) for a database view, then stores this in a global variable

```
my $dmlRef = $db->query($sql) || die "cannot query the db $! \n for sql: $sql";
our $dml =  $dmlRef->[0]->{'DML'};
```

when I print this dml in  a sub (print "$main::dml\n") , it looks like this:

"... from schema.MY_CALL_LOG ..."

the dml is a series of common table expressions so there are lots of schemas mentioned in it in the same style as above.

so I then have a sub, where I try and find if my list of schemas are in this, using the global variable I saved the dml to:

```
sub is_in_view_dll {
        my $schema = shift || die "no schema passed in";
        if ($main::dml =~ m/FROM\s+$schema\.MY_CALL_LOG/ig){ ##use global variable $dml here
                print "found $schema in dml!\n";
        }else{
                print "couldn't find $schema in dml \n";
        }
```

when I use this, I find that the perl fails to regex match some of the schema names in my list, despite me checking that a) they are in the dml b) the case matches up in my schema list (which has no spaces in the names of schemas)

When I instead make a local copy of the global $dml variable, I find that perl regex works as expected

```
sub is_in_view_dll {
        my $schema = shift || die "no schema passed in";
        my $localdml = "$main::dml";
        if ($localdml =~ m/FROM\s+$schema\.MY_CALL_LOG/ig){ ##search through local copy of global var 
                print "found $schema in dml!\n";            ##works correctly
        }else{
                print "couldn't find $schema in dml \n";
        }
```

I can't understand why using the global variable directly "$main::dml" didn't work for all the attempts to match, while using the local copy of it in the regex in the sub did work

### Further information / how to replicate

I have created a stripped back example where I can replicate this issue (and you hopefully can too) with the data/input that is being generated included as a string stored in the our $dml variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I/usr/local/lib/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

our $dml = <<EOM

  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "GWMONITORING"."MY_CALL_LOG" ("OWNER", "DAY", "HOUR", "USERNAME", "CALL_ID") AS
  SELECT
    'DEMOGW'                                AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    DEMOGW.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'ARMYS'                                    AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    ARMYS.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GFW'                                     AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    GFW.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GLOBE'                                   AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    GLOBE.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'VARS'                                   AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    VARS.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'ALLHH'                                    AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    ALLHH.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GW'                                     AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    GW.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'QUEEN'                                   AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    QUEEN.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GEORGEY'                                 AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    GEORGEY.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'MONKEYS'                                 AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    MONKEYS.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'MYPAQS'                                AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    MYPAQS.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GWINV'                                   AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    GWINV.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'PRIMER'                                  AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    PRIMER.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GWSTIM'                                AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    GWSTIM.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GFW2'                                    AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    GFW2.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GPETW'                                    AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    GPETW.MY_CALL_LOG
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GWAHG'                                    AS OWNER,
    TRUNC (TIME_START)                          DAY,
    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TIME_START, 'HH24'))    HOUR,
    USERNAME,
    CALL_ID
FROM
    GWAHG.MY_CALL_LOG
EOM
;

my @schemas = qw(GW GWAHG GPETW GFW2 GFW GWSTIM DEMOGW GWINV GLOBE PRIMER ARMYS MONKEYS QUEEN VARS ALLHH MYPAQS GEORGEY );

foreach(@schemas){
        is_in_view($_);
}


sub is_in_view {
        my $owner = shift || die "no owner passed in";
        my $localdml = "$main::dml";

        if ($localdml  !~ m/FROM\s+$owner\.MY_CALL_LOG/ig){  ##when you use this line, should find no matches fail to be found
        #if ($main::dml !~ m/FROM\s+$owner\.MY_CALL_LOG/ig){  ##when you use this line, should find that some matches fail to be found. For me this was GPETW, GFW DEMOGW GLOBE ARMYS QUEEN GEORGEY
                print "$owner is not in the dml for GWMONITORING\.MY_CALL_LOG\n";
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some input data, and how you call that function please?

Comment: What are you using the `g` modifier (`m/.../ig`) for?

Comment: You don't make a "local copy" of the global variable, you take a stringified copy of it (interpolated in a double quoted string). It is likely some sort of object to some undisclosed module, which reacts differently when subjected to a regex match. Tell us what module the `$db->query` statement comes from, and we might have a clue how to help you.

Comment: @JimDavis to be honest I just used g there I always do (force of habit). I only intend to match once here really to prove it works. I have tried it with and without the g modifier, its only when I use a local copy of the $main::dml that I see the regex work as expected

Comment: thanks for getting in touch @TLP - the library I am using is an internal company module (bespoke) so I can't share this, but I can say that essentially it use's the perl DBI library to return an array ref (i.e. $ref = $q_h->fetchrow_hashref())  which is then added to an array and returned. I have tried your idea and set the global variable using:     my $dmlRef = $db->query($sql);     our $dml =  "$dmlRef->[0]->{'DML'}";     but this likewise give the expected output until I create a local copy of $main::dml in the sub

Comment: @simbabque sorry for the late response - I have added code to my original post above  which replicates the issue I found - please see the comments in the code around the regex to try and replicate this and see if you have any ideas what might be causing it

Comment: @Georgec: I can reproduce the problem on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (don't ask), using a home-built Perl 5.30.0 as described.  Which version of Perl are you using on which platform?  I don't have any explanation for what you're seeing — I can only report that I see problems with "GPETW", "GFW", "DEMOGW", "GLOBE", "ARMYS", "QUEEN", "GEORGEY" showing up as not in the DML one way, and all showing up present in the other.

Comment: @Georgec Not sure that was my idea. You could always try printing the two different versions of the variable with `Data::Dumper` and see how they are different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler cheers for trying that - I'm running this on Amazon Linux (4.14.181-140.257.amzn2.x86_64) using perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi. I'm quite unsure whats going on too really; I'll try out a few more things, see if anyone else has any ideas, then will post a perlbug. Will update this when I find an answer

Comment: @TLP sorry for putting words in your mouth there, I have tried out your suggestion just then and wrote both variables to tmp files using Dumper, but "diff tmp.global tmp.local" shows no differences

Comment: Yeah, this definitely smells like a perl bug. If you write `my $localdml = $dml.'';` then it also works. Or if you delete a few selects from the string then, again, works. I've tried this on perl, 5.18.2 on an old ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex engine storing the last position and starting at that position for the next match (under /g):

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = 'bar foo bar baz';

for my $pat (qw/bar foo bar foo/){
    if ($string =~ /$pat/g){
        print "\nmatch for $pat\n"
    }
    else{
        print "\nno match for $pat\n"
    }
    print pos $string;
}
```

prints:

```
match for bar
3
match for foo
7
match for bar
11
no match for foo
Use of uninitialized value in print at command.pl line 13.
```

The last match will fail, because there is no 'foo' after pos 11 in the string.

If you add a debug print for `pos $main::dml` to your function or reset pos each time `pos($main::dml) = 0;` you will see the effect.

Note that pos gets reset after a failing match.

See [perlrequick](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick#More-matching) for reference.